# The argument does not represent an annotation type: Deployment with Arquillian

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, jboss-arquillian

I try to implement Arquillian for unit tests into my maven project.

This is the pom.xml of my project:

```
 <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>op.coma</groupId>
        <artifactId>op-interfaces-coma</artifactId> <!-- where i have all my entities -->
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>ejbModule/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>ejbModule</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-ejb-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>${ejb.version}</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>op.coma</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <finalName>${artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <childDelegation>true</childDelegation>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true</argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>ejbModule/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>${h2.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                </testResource>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <java.util.logging.config.file>
                                ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
                            </java.util.logging.config.file>
                            <derby.stream.error.file>
                                ${project.build.directory}/derby.log
                            </derby.stream.error.file>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

This is my test Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PersonFactoryTest extends Arquillian {    
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive  createDeployment() {
    JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addPackage(PersonFactory.class.getPackage())
            .addAsManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource("jbossas-ds.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    return jar;
}
@BeforeTest
private void insertData() {
    Person person = new Person();;
    person.setName("TestName");
    person.setLastName("TestLastName");
    person.setClientId(10);
}
@Test
public void findListByIDClientTest() throws Exception {
    int i=12;
    Assert.assertTrue(i==14);
}}
```

This is the glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC
"-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool"
    jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian"/>
<jdbc-connection-pool name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool"
    res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    datasource-classname="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
    <property name="user" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:target/databases/h2/db"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

For the  test-persistence.xml and persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="test">
   <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
     <properties>
     <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
     </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When i make a maven clean and install it gives me the following errors:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The argument does not represent an annotation type: Deployment
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(JavacRoundEnvironment.java:119)
at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor.process(ConstraintValidationProcessor.java:107)
...
```

Comment: Please add your imports.

Comment: @John Ament , it's done

Comment: Why have you changed the source and test source folder instead of using the defaults? I would suggest to use the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above PersonFactoryTest you should use the @RunWith(Arquillian.class)

I have recently written some Arquillian tests for a HTTP Resource Apaptor see https://github.com/ozoli/http-jca-adaptor Hope this helps!

Comment: i don't use Junit to use RunWith(Arquillian.class) but as you see i use testng